# dojo datagrid OnStyleRow not correct after sorting via header

Tags: datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am styling grid row based on a value in the column.

On initial load it looks ok, however, when I click on the header to sort, the styling follows the original style and does not reflect the value in the sorted list.

In the **onStyleRow** event that does the styling override, I can get the row object of the grid, **But... how do I get the column data from the row so that I can style it properly**.

I have gone through the two questions below and a few others in StackOverflow, Googled, checked Dojo API docs and reference, etc. So far no outcome...

[dojox DataGrid onStyleRow works first time, then not again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132559/dojox-datagrid-onstylerow-works-first-time-then-not-again)

[dojo datagrid custom sorting server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128547/dojo-datagrid-custom-sorting-server-side)

I attach working code below, you can cut and paste to a html file to run and see the problem I am facing (The **////** comment in the code below is a key place to note).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true,isDebug:true,parseOnLoad:true"></script>
<script>        
var grid_report;
require([ 'dojo/parser', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojox/data/CsvStore', 'dojo/domReady!' ],  function(){
dojo.ready(function(){
    var csvData = "id,val\n";
    csvData += "1,10\n" + "2,20\n" + "3,30\n" + "4,40\n" + "5,50\n" + "6,60\n";
    var csv_store = new dojox.data.CsvStore({identifier: "id", data: csvData});

    grid_report = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        style:'height:400px',
        store: csv_store,
        structure: [ { field: 'id', width: '80px', name: 'ID' }, { field: 'val', width: '80px', name: 'Value' }, ],
    }, document.createElement('div'));

    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid_report.domNode);

    dojo.connect(grid_report, 'onStyleRow', function (row) {
        var idx = row.index;
        //// Below is not correct as index is the row index on the grid, but the data store is in a different order after sorting order change via clicking cell header
        var _item = grid_report.getItem(idx);
        if (!_item) return;

        var val = parseInt( _item._csvStore._dataArray[ idx ][1] );
        if (val <= 20) row.customStyles += 'background-color:#88f;';
        else if (val > 40) row.customStyles += 'background-color:#f88;';
        else row.customStyles += 'background-color:#ff8;';
        dojox.grid.DataGrid.prototype.onStyleRow.apply(this, arguments);
    });
    grid_report.startup();    
}); // end ready
}); // end require
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <div style="height:25px; width:100px; display:table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#88f;">Value 0-20</div>
    <div style="height:25px; width:100px; display:table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#ff8;">Value 21-40 </div>
    <div style="height:25px; width:100px; display:table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#f88;">Value 41 or more</div>
    <div id="gridDiv" style="width:'800px';height:'600px';"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any ideas? Any one? I would hate to dig into the source to write a workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. It is not ideal as it may not work for all situations.

Change line with:

```
var idx = row.index;
```

to:

```
var idx = -1;
```

After the  newly edit line above, add the following:

```
var _item = null;
grid_report.store.fetch({onComplete: function(items) {
    dojo.forEach(items, function(item, index) {
        // KLUDGE FOR finding item after sort
        // use merged csv data AND row.node.textContent
        var merged_csv_text = item._csvStore._dataArray[index].join('');
        if (merged_csv_text == row.node.textContent) {
            idx = index; // I finally get the correct index here!!!
            return;
        }
    });
} });
if (idx ==  -1) return;
```

This works  only if each data formed by **merged_csv_text** is unique.